# Unity - Blender - Object in Unity gets wrong pivot

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.67

**--** **Edit Solution** : **Set unity to rotate around "pivot" instead of "center".**

I created an prisma in blender and exported it as .fbx into unity. In the scene Im rotating it via code and I noticed that its rotating around the wrong pivot.

The problem is that I set in blender all objects to the same origin and that should work without problems. But its not working and Im going crazy....

**Why I think its the pivot** - By using the rotating tool in unity I can see it with my eyes and when rotating the position of the prisma changes.

**To rotate my object the right way I used** - https://answers.unity.com/questions/319802/rotation-when-importing-from-blender.html

Below you can see both views (looking from top on the prisma), **first** from **Blender**, where the origin is in the center of the object and in the **second** image you see it in **unity** but the pivot is wrong/changed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the allignment is matching in the X,Y and Z dimensions? You could have it upside down.

Comment: Yeah I guess. When set it up in the scene it looks the right way. I followed the step by this guy: https://answers.unity.com/questions/319802/rotation-when-importing-from-blender.html

I just screenshot the objects from top to see that the pivot changed a little bit. The direction of the arrow/axis are not important in this situation

Comment: It has been some time since I have worked with blender. But IMO you should confirm this, it can occur that u have it differently rotated towards what you might expect. Try and figure out the X,Y and Z Axis in blender and confirm for sure from values that it is correct - accordingly to Unity. Judgement by simply viewing it can be the reason for it to be overseen. :-) Else I cannot see where the issue lies

Comment: Can you perhaps display a screenshot (like those two you have now) but from a 90 deg angle to the object?

Comment: just guessing, did you - maybe by accident - set unity to rotate around "center" instead of "pivot"?

Comment: @yes You are right o.O I never touched the tool handle, which was by default on center. Switching it on pivot fixed it... never saw/used the tool handel-buttons

Comment: I use this plugin.  https://www.blendernation.com/2017/08/29/bs-modify-pivot-add/ Moving the mesh pivot is/was a weak area in blender

Comment: @yes u can post your answer beneath, so I can select it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right answer was given by the user [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219084/yes): "[...] set unity to rotate around `center` instead of `pivot`"